# ¿Cómo utilizar la función number_format() de php?

Tags: php, function

Necesito dar formato a esta cantidad utilizando la función php  number_format()

Esta es la cantidad : 10591276

Este es el formato de salida que necesito 1,059.1276

Desde ya muchísimas gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido por favor lee [ask], que has hecho? por favor edita y amplia

Answer (score 3):

El problema es que el valor no tiene el punto decimal, por lo que cualquier manipulación con `number_format` se revela difícil y sujeta a imprecisiones.

Una cosa que puedes hacer es colocar primero el punto decimal en la posición que corresponde con `substr_replace` y luego aplicar `number_format`.

```
$mNumber = 10591276;
#Coloca el punto decimal en la posición 4 contando desde la izquierda
$newNumber = substr_replace($mNumber, ".", -4, 0);
$finalNumber = number_format($newNumber, 4, '.', ',');
echo $finalNumber;
```

**Salida:**

```
1,059.1276
```

Comment: Gracias Sr A, Cedano

a un asi me arroja el siguiente error :  Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered.

al verificar los números que deseo formatear veo que tienen  un punto, a esto puede deberse el error, aquí le dejo un ejemplo de los numeros que deseo formatear.

1363.696450

100.063335

100.063335

Gracias por su valiosa ayuda Sr Cedano.

Comment: @MaicolRomero, ningún pánico, puedes crear la variable así: `$newNumber = substr_replace(str_replace(".","",$mNumber), ".", -4,0);` y luego aplicarle `number_format`. Para que no de problemas con el cero al final, por ejemplo aquí: `1363.696450` es mejor que declares esos datos como cadenas: `$mNumber="1363.696450";`, el resultado será: `136,369.6450`

Comment: Excelente, Muchisimas gracias, solo vasto con agregar (float), feliz noche Sr Cedano.