# De un total, sacar el subtotal y el IVA 21% - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php7

Buenas necesito sacar de un total, sacar el subtotal y el IVA 21%.

Recibo esto:

```
"363,00"
```

Pruebo de este modo pero me da error:

```
@php $mi = $total/1.21 @endphp
```

Me devuelve este error.

```
A non well formed numeric value encountered
```

Estoy utilizando el shopping cart de laravel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que es porque el valor que te imprime es un string no un tipo numerico intenta con

```
@php $mi = (float)$total/1.21 @endphp
```

Lo que hace es realizar una conversión de string a tipo flotante en este caso que tienes decimales

**Edit**

A manera de ejemplo te colo un Getter el cual busca traer el total del detalle de un carrito de compras

```
 public function getTotalAttribute()//debe comenzar con get y en convención camel case el nombre que tendra, terminando con Attribute
    {
        $total = 0; // defino una variable
        foreach ($this->details as $detail) {
            $total += $detail->quantity * $detail->product->price;
        } // Realizo un foreach por cada elemento en el carrito de compras y lo multiplico por el precio para obtener el total

        return $total; // retorno la variable
    }
```

y en la vista todo lo que hago es llamar al getter `{{ auth()->user()->cart->total }}` // ya que el carrito de compras tiene relacion con el usuario, accedo de esta manera

Comment: Hola gracias por tu comentario @Dohko19 se puede formatear para que solo salgan dos decimales? y haga redondeo?

Comment: De este modo lo que pasa es que no me coje los decimales entonces si el importe es 508,20€ solo coge los 508€, alguna sugerencia @Dohko19

Comment: ese total de donde lo recibes?

Comment: me lo traer de forma natural shopping cart de laravel

Comment: porque no haces un getter para que te calcule el total automaticamente?

Comment: El problema que shopping cart funciona genial, pero el cliente quiere que los precios de los productos se muestren ya con el iva, y con shopping cart me añade los impuestos en el carrito

Comment: `number_format((float)$total/1.21, 2, '.', '');` Intenta con este modo para q te muestre dos decimales

Comment: Con el getter es igual mero demotrativo tu decides si llevarte ese valor o no

Comment: Una pregunta como es mejor guardar el importe de un producto en una bd? ejp) 1260 o 1.256,00 o 1256,00

Comment: Segun tengo entendido la mejor manera es tal cual marcas el campo, double o float, no hay porque agregar "," o "." para los millares, solos se agregan si hay decimanles o miles aun asi la cantidad hay funciones de JS o php que te pueden mostrar catidades como tu lo desees

Comment: Esque ayer añadi mskinput a los inputs para que las cifras siempre las pongan así 1456,00€ , es un error?

Comment: Y conoces otro modo para hacer lo de los productos con iva, esque tengo que trastocar muchas cosas, que si restar iva, etc..

Comment: Depende de como te lo guarde en la base de datos, en realidad la convencion normal seria, solo el numero seria lo correcto ya
en las vistas es cuando le das el formato que requieres, y en Laravel hay algo que se llaman getters y setter te puede ayudar mucho a 
simplificar todo

Comment: Y es correcto lo que voy hacer, restarles el iva y que el producto ya se ponga con el iva. Tengo un cierto lio con esto, el proyecto ya estaba terminado y ahora no se que hacer para cambiar lo menos posible

Comment: Edito una manera de implementar un Setter

Comment: Hola @Dohko19 el problema esta que cuando añado un producto de más de 1000€ la división de 1.21 la realiza mal, por ejemplo 1,350.00€ me saca 1.12€ , sabes el motivo por el que parece que haga algo raro con los decimales?

Comment: Icluso si hago una prueba `number_format((float)$subtotal, 2, '.', '');` sin dividir me saca 3.5 @Dohko19

Comment: 1.35 perdón! no se porque!

Comment: Entinces la division la realizas mal?

Comment: Yo creo que recibo 1,350.10 por ejemplo entonces esa como no la detecta, podemos hablar por chat, para no llenar esto?? @Dohko19

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111454/discussion-between-miguel-and-dohko19).

Answer (score 1):

Recibes ese **NOTICE** debido a que desde la versión 7.1 de [PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/migration71.other-changes.php) tienes 2 posibles escenarios:

- Notificación si algún valor de la operación no es numérico
- Advertencia si ninguno de los valores usados es numérico

> Entonces dado eso como te muestran deberás hacer un cast para pasar un valor de un tipo de dato a otro

Comment: Como se hace ese `cast` @BetaM ya que con el float me quita los decimales

Comment: @Miguel revisa esto https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/248791/c%C3%B3mo-utilizar-la-funci%C3%B3n-number-format-de-php

Comment: Hola @BetaM lo de number_format ya lo estoy gastando, el problema que cuando el importe supera los 1000€ la división de 1.21 ya no lo hace bien, sabes porque puede ser?

Comment: Es que al pasar de 1000€ me trae esto mi variable `"1.100,00"` pero al hacer `$mi = (float)$subtotal/1.21` me trae `0.90909090909091` que puedo hacer @BetaM

Comment: Dame oportunidad, en cuanto tenga un espacio te aporto una solución